# Locate, regexp_replace UDFs Hive to replace string in a column

Tags: hive

I have a table like below

```
names    age  gender
v_mark   25   male
j_david  26   male
S_Rose   28   Female
mark     21   male
```

First I need to findout the name values contains "underscore" or not, Then
I need to replace "underscore" with "space" or "comma" the **name** values based on the specific condition.

If gender is male, I need to replace "underscore" with space
If gender is female, I need to replace "underscore" with comma.

I did search in google, and I found that I need use Locate (to check the "underscore" is there in the value) and regexp_replace (To replace the underscore with comma based on condition)  I tried `When` and `Case` but getting error. Below is my code.

```
CASE
(
WHEN LOCATE("_",Table1.names)-1 > 0 AND Table1.gender='male'  THEN regexp_replace(T1.names, "_"," ")
WHEN LOCATE("_",Table1.names)-1 > 0 AND Table1.gender='Female'  THEN regexp_replace(T1.names, "_",",")
ELSE Table1.names
END
    ) AS names1
```

I need the output like

```
names1    age  gender
v mark   25   male
j david  26   male
S,Rose   28   Female
mark     21   male
```

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue is with **'('**  after case use below code

CASE
WHEN LOCATE("_",Table1.names)-1 > 0 AND Table1.gender='male'  THEN regexp_replace(T1.names, "*"," ")
WHEN LOCATE("*",Table1.names)-1 > 0 AND Table1.gender='Female'  THEN regexp_replace(T1.names, "_",",")
ELSE Table1.names
END
    AS names1

Answer (score 0):

Case statements and Regex will give you the desired results.

```
SELECT 
  CASE gender
    WHEN 'male' THEN regexp_replace(names, "_"," ")
    WHEN 'Female' THEN regexp_replace(names, "_",",")
  END AS names, 
  age, 
  gender
FROM table;
```